# Authenticate TPM using tpm2-tools

Tags: tpm

I've got a bunch of servers with TPM2 onboard and I'd like to authenticate their TPMs. How can I accomplish that using tpm2-tools? I would like to do the following:

1. Get TPM Attestation certificate (where can I find such a certificate?)
2. Generate a key pair inside a TPM
3. Make TPM sign the generated private key with it's attestation key
4. Make TPM sign a random challenge with the generated private key

Just to clarify all the things I'd like to get something close to [PIV Attestation in Yubikeys](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-piv-tool/Attestation.html) as it's easy to use and to understand. Can I do the same with TPM2 and tpm2-tools?

Comment: 1) You probably want to verify the EK certificate. See the 2nd picture [here](https://google.github.io/tpm-js/#pg_certificates). 2-4) Do you want to write C code? If so, use the Enhanced System API  (ESAPI) provided by [tpm2-tss](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss). If you want to use bash tools, use the [tpm2-tools](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools).

Comment: Am I right that I can create EK, then create a key pair under storage hierarchy and run TPM2_Certify to get the pub key signed with EK?